# Keep Upload Data for Analyses in Flask Session

Tags: python, flask

I am very much struggling with a concept and hope someone can offer a code implementation suggestion. I have the following route embedded within my flask app. After working on this for a few days I *think* I now see the nature of the issue. I have modified my code based on suggestion below in comments.

In the web app now, the names of the data frame columns populate a drop down menu and the user can choose one of those variables and click "Show". That variable name then prints to the screen just so I know my POST from the form is communicating with my function in the flask app.

What I would like to do is create a temp version of the file uploaded so that it exists as long as the web session is open (or is overwritten if a new file upload occurs). Then, the user chooses a variable from the drop down menu and the mean of that variable is computed (that part is commented out in the code below for now but you can see what I have tried).

If the user reads in a new file, then the same process would occur on that new file.

Thanks for any suggestions or supports.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import binom  
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.stats import norm 
from scipy import optimize 
from pyodbc import connect 
import pandas as pd 
import os
import tempfile


app = Flask(__name__)
    @app.route('/dataTools', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def data_tools_upload():
    tempfile_path = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile().name
    if request.files:
        df = pd.read_csv(request.files.get('file'))
        #tempfile_path = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile().name 
        df.to_csv(tempfile_path)
    if os.path.exists(tempfile_path):
        orig_df = pd.read_csv(tempfile_path)
        vars = list(orig_df.columns)
        var2use = request.form.get("var2use")
        #indx = vars.index(var2use)
        #df[vars[indx]].mean()
        mean = orig_df[vars[4]].mean()
        dims = orig_df.shape
        message = 'You have data! There are %s rows and %s columns and the variable %s has mean %s' % (dims[0],dims[1],vars[4],round(mean,3))
        table = orig_df.head(10).to_html(classes='data', header = "true")
        return render_template('upload.html', tables = [table], message = message, vars = vars, var_name = var2use)
    var2use = request.form.get("var2use")
    return render_template('upload.html', var_name = var2use, message = "What happened?") 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And then the following HTML bit (upload.html):

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}    
{% block body %}

<h3> Read in a data file </h3>

<br>

<form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
    <input type=file name=file class = "btn btn-outline-secondary">
    <input type=submit value=Upload class = "btn btn-outline-secondary">
</form>

<br>    

<form class="form-inline" action = "{{url_for('data_tools_upload')}}" method = "POST">
    <select type = "text" name="var2use" class="custom-select mr-sm-1">
        {% for var in vars %}
            <option value= "{{ var }}" SELECTED>{{ var }}</option>"
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
        <button class = "btn btn-primary"> Show </button>
</form>


<center>
    <h1>
    {{message}}
    {{name}}
    </h1>
    <br>
        <small>
        {% for table in tables %}
                    {{ table|safe }}
        {% endfor %}

        {% endblock %}
        </small>
</center>
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to save file to work with it (the code works perfectly in my app):

```
        f = request.files['file']
        tmp_filename = '/tmp/my_tmp_file.csv'
        f.save(tmp_filename)
        pd.read_csv(tmp_filename)
```

Here is the detailed documentation on Flask file uploads:
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/

Full example for your case is below. I think you might have problems with the following three items:

1. Uploading the file because of form enctype (should be "multipart/form-data")
2. Uploading because of file size (try my sample)
3. Processing the form with empty file overwriting yours (see my example for "csv_file_uploaded")

**Python (csv_test.py):**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pandas as pd
import os

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    data = {}
    tmp_filename = '/tmp/csv_test.csv'
    if request.files:
        csv_file_uploaded = request.files.get('file')
        if csv_file_uploaded:
            f = request.files['file']
            f.save(tmp_filename)
    if os.path.exists(tmp_filename):
        df = pd.read_csv(tmp_filename)
        data['columns'] = ', '.join(df.columns)
        col_selected = request.form.get('col_selected')
        print(col_selected)
        data['col_selected'] = col_selected
        if col_selected:
            mean = df.get(col_selected).mean()
            data['mean'] = mean
    return render_template('csv_test.tpl', data=data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

**Flask template (csv_test.tpl):**

```
<html><head><title>CSV TEST</title></head>
    <body><h1>CSV TEST</h1>
      {% if data %}
          <div>Columns of the uploaded file: <strong>{{ data.columns }}</strong></div>
          <div>Selected column: <strong>{{ data.col_selected }}</strong></div>
          <div>Mean of the selected = <strong>{{ data.mean }}</strong></div>
      {% endif %}
      <fieldset>
         <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
            <h2>Provide some CSV with first column in numbers and/or column name</h2>
            <div>File{% if data.columns %} (UPLOADED){% endif %}: <input id="file" type="file" name="file"/></div>
            <div>Column: <input id="col_selected" type="text" name="col_selected" value="{{ data.col_selected }}"/></div>
            <div><input id="submit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT"/></div>
         </form>
      </fieldset>
</body></html>
```

**CSV file (123.csv) - use it to test the form:**

```
col1,col2
1,2
2,3
3,4
5,6
```

Comment: This is helpful, thank you! Will give this code a try. Does this save it only in the working session and the disappear when the browser is closed? OR is it saved perpetually on the server?

Comment: You can save it to some persistent file if you wish, of course, but then you have it for all the clients of your application. If you want to have data for the specific session then use session object "from flask import session", read more in https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.session (do not forget to set "session.modified = True" as described there - it is important)

Comment: I'm grateful for you reply. However, I'm finding it does not work. Perhaps my frustration is keeping me from being successful, but I'm about to throw flask away from my toolbox. Does anyone know if there is a minimal reproducible example showing how to read in a .csv file and do stuff to do (e.g., choose a variable in the data from a drop down and compute a statistic on that column)

Comment: Added the full working and tested example. Flask is not so bad, but I think that Python in common is not about web. I had a lot of good experience with other languages.

Comment: I'm almost there with your suggestions, but for some reason wasn't able to get your code to run. So, I blended the code from your suggestion with something I also worked on my own. I feel like I'm almost there but not quite. My question above has been modified based on the suggestions.

Comment: Just put my code in the files (you can see the filenames there as well, csv_test.tpl should be in "templates" folder, so name it "templates/csv_test.tpl") then run "python csv_test.py". After that you will see that the web-server is started, just open http://localhost:5000/ and use 123.csv for testing. There is nothing more to do to make it work. If you have something that already uses port 5000 then turn it off first.